# Train from Krakow to Berlin

Tags: trains, berlin, krakow, eurail

Is there a train from Krakow to Berlin (e.g Krakow - Warsaw - Berlin)? I am told that there isn't one any longer.

https://www.europebyrail.eu/the-wawel-tale

https://www.eurocheapo.com/blog/deutsche-bahn-new-long-distance-bus-services.html

Comment: I wonder if Ukrainian railways run anything on that route.

Comment: @alamar Wonder no longer. Ukrainian railways doesn't run anything in Poland.

Comment: @RHA Why, they have trains that run to Poznan, but not further to Berlin.

Comment: @alamar They might run international trains, but why would you look at Ukrainian railways for a route within Poland?

Comment: @RHA because Polish direct trains are not available. Neither are Ukrainian ones but it was worth checking.

Comment: Or you can take the Flixbus (https://www.flixbus.pl/ )- approx.6h journey from KRakow to Berlin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct train. You have to change in Warsaw or Poznan.

However, via the webiste of the German Railways (bahn.de), it is possible to book a bus from Berlin to Krakow for 29 EUR. There are also other operatoirs on that route (e.g. Eurolines).

The following thread may be relevant too

[What is the cheapest way of traveling from Berlin to Krakow?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16627/what-is-the-cheapest-way-of-traveling-from-berlin-to-krakow)

Comment: Having completed this trip, I did have to change trains at Poznan.  Only thing is the state of Poland's trains...BYO blanket to sit on...